# How to add different instances of the same JPanel class without overwriting

Tags: java, javascript, swing, jcombobox

So the issue I am having is that I have made a class which extends JPanel (seen below) and I am trying to add multiple instances of this JPanel class to another JPanel class.

```
public class DOBGui extends JPanel {
  private static String dayList[] = {bunch of days};
  private static JComboBox dobDay = new JComboBox(dayList);
  private static String monthList[] = {bunch of months};
  private static JComboBox dobMonth = new JComboBox(monthList);
  private static String yearList[] = {bunch of dates};
  private static JComboBox dobYear = new JComboBox(yearList);

  public static String DOBString() {

    int dayInt = dobDay.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
    int monthInt = dobMonth.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
    String year = dobYear.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String day = "" + dayInt;
    if (day.length() == 1) {
      day = "0" + day;
    }

    String month = "" + monthInt;
    if (month.length() == 1) {
      month = "0" + month;
    }

    return day + month + year;
  }

  public DOBGui() {
    add(dobDay);
    add(dobMonth);
    add(dobYear);
  }

  void reset() {
    dobDay.setSelectedIndex(0);
    dobMonth.setSelectedIndex(0);
    dobYear.setSelectedIndex(0);
  }
}
```

And I am trying to add this JPanel to another JPanel class twice by creating two instances of the class DOBGui but it is overwriting the first one.

```
questionsPanel.add(new JLabel("Date for budget skills training session"), "wrap");
DOBGui budgetSkillsDate = new DOBGui();
budgetSkillsDate.reset();
questionsPanel.add(budgetSkillsDate, "wrap");

questionsPanel.add(new JLabel("Date for cooking course training session"), "wrap");
DOBGui cookingCourseDate = new DOBGui();
cookingCourseDate.reset();
questionsPanel.add(cookingCourseDate, "wrap");
```

Comment: The fields should not be static.

Comment: Nah it has to be static otherwise I cannot reference the dobstring from an actionlistener.

Answer (score 0):

That's because all your field you have defined is of static type. Now when you call reset on panel1, you call:

```
 void reset() {
    dobDay.setSelectedIndex(0);
    dobMonth.setSelectedIndex(0);
    dobYear.setSelectedIndex(0);
 }
```

You reset day, month, year. Then you set it back and then for second panel you call reset which means you have just one instance of dobDay, dobMonth, dobYear and all your panel play around with just one that instance.

Comment: This is not the issue, I removed the void reset method and removed where I called it.

Comment: change your static fields to non static and your method too and that would resolve the issue. I just gave an example.

Comment: No this did not work either because I am calling DOBString from an actionListener. String sql = "SELECT * FROM clientDetails WHERE dob='"+DOBGui.DOBString()+"'";

Comment: @DanielBudworth-Mead DOBString should not be static, either. If the fields are not instance fields - they will be overridden. That's Java.

Comment: [What should I do about this then?](http://i.imgur.com/Lzx0jPy.png) As it is in my action listener.

Comment: You should update the code in your question. Also you might need to have an instance of GUI and use that same accross.

Answer (score 0):

The short version is: the fields should not be static.

Static fields are fields that are not part of the object (instance), but part of the class. The classic example is objects that have serial numbers. The "serial number" field is unique to each instance, and so it has to be an instance field. But the field that contains the "next serial number to give" belongs to the class, not to any of the actual instances, and is used in the process of creating new instances.

When a compiler tells you that "non-static XXX cannot be accessed from static context", in most cases it doesn't mean you should convert XXX to static. It means that you should be using an *instance* of the class, instead of the class as a whole.

What did you intend `DOBString()` to do? You have no documentation in your code, but I'm guessing that it is meant to give you a string representation of the date selected by the sub-components. But isn't this date different for each individual `DOBGui` object? If you have two `DOBGui` objects in your application at the same time, and the user selects January 15th, 2014 in one, and July 28th, 1969 in the other, then `DOBString()` should return a different string for the first than it does for the second. It makes no sense to call `DOBGui.DOBString()`, because what date is that supposed to return? The first or the second? A general default date?

So everything that is supposed to be part of the individual panel (the fields and the methods that access them or do stuff with them) should *not* be static. Not the fields, not the methods.

What about your event listener, then? Well, which of the panels' date do you want it to display? If you want it to display `budgetSkillsDate`'s date, then it should call `budgetSkillsDate.DOBString()`. For this to work, `budgetSkillsDate` should not be a local variable, but a field accessible by both the method that creates it, and the listener.

The important thing is that it has to be an *instance* of `DOBGui`, not the *class* `DOBGui`, because that doesn't make any sense - the class shouldn't represent a date. It's *instances* should.

Notes:

- Method names should not start with a capital letter. Only type names start with capital letters. Syntax highlighters expect it to be like this, and so it becomes confusing if you don't follow the convention.
- You really should have more documentation in your code. It's hard to guess what you wanted to do when there is not a single comment in the code.